# C# limit the hour with minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

i want to enable the checkbox only between 12:30 -- 14:00 and 18:00 -- 21:00.

```
if (((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 || DateTime.Now.Minute >= 30) && DateTime.Now.Hour < 14) || (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 18 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 21))
        { ASPxCheckBox_ForceClot.Enabled = true; }
```

the problem is minute, 12:30

```
DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 || DateTime.Now.Minute >= 30
```

it reject 12:45 but it should take this value

```
 DateTime.Now.Hour >= 12 && DateTime.Now.Minute >= 30
```

it reject 13:12 but it should take this value

thanks in advance

Comment: What you want to ask? what is the issue, please explain in details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the suggestions to use actual DateTime or TimeSpan objects are good, the real problem is that your boolean logic is flawed.

You should write something like

```
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

bool enabled =
    now >= new TimeSpan(12, 30, 0) && now < new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0) ||
    now >= new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0) && now < new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0);
```

UPDATE: This is basically the same answer as given by Jon Skeet, which I only saw after submitting.

Also, be aware that time progresses. Depending on your requirements, you might have to set up a timer to change the state of the checkbox when it's time to do so.

Comment: I would personally use brackets to make the precedence of `&&` and `||` clearer. Even if it's correct (I can't remember offhand) it's much clearer to *readers* if it's explicit.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is often clearer to readers, and I often do it myself. But usually not in a case like this one, where the calculation is a disjunction of conjuntions, and each conjunction goes on its own line. Also, in all languages I know of, conjunction has precedence over disjunction, as it does in math. BTW, this is analogous to the precedence of multiplication over addition. In fact, in algebra, conjunction is the boolean multiplication (`&& true` doesn't change the result; `&& false` makes everything false), and disjunction is the boolean addition (`|| false` doesn't change the result).

Comment: I would do it even in this case - obviously the compiler doesn't care that it's all on one line; it really depends on the language rules, and I'd rather be explicit in this than memorize the rules. Do you think it's *less* clear with the explicit bracketing?

Comment: I don't think it's less clear with the brackets, just as _to_ _me_ it isn't clearer with them. Brackets might improve readability, just as indentation and linebreaks do. But note that adding too much brackets _can_ make code unreadable, especially when you have so many that you need to count them to understand the code. The compiler will generate the exact same code, so this is really a matter of style. In a team project, I often enforce style rules using StyleCop, and that would tell me to add the brackets. And I would add them. And I would still use linebreaks as well.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with remembering the language rules? You do so with other language rules, such as what `internal` visibility means (in C#) or `package` visibility (in Java). Those are language rules. In fact, this operator precendence is less of a language rule. No language would have `||` have higher precedence than `&&`, of `+` higher than `*`, those rules are universal because of the math underlying them. That being said, I don't disagree with your point of view, only trying to enrich it with a view from a different angle.

Comment: I do so with some language rules, and some aspects of precedence - but only the ones which I expect other people to learn as well. I wouldn't expect `||` to be *higher* than `&&`, but I wouldn't be surprised if they were equal, just as with `*` and `/`.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you do it by actual times of day (represented as `TimeSpan` values) instead:

```
var firstPeriodStart = new TimeSpan(12, 30, 0);
var firstPeriodEnd = new TimeSpan(14, 0, 0);

var secondPeriodStart = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0);
var secondPeriodEnd = new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0);

DateTime time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

if ((time >= firstPeriodStart && time < firstPeriodEnd) ||
    (time >= secondPeriodStart && time < secondPeriodEnd))
{
    ASPxCheckBox_ForceClot.Enabled = true;
}
```

Better yet (IMO) use the `LocalTime` type in [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) as that represents what you're really interested in.

You should also bear in mind that the code above uses the local time on the *server* - if your users are in a different time zone, is that okay?

Comment: You beat me again! By the gods Mr Skeet, one day I will out-type you!

Comment: @LolCoder: Darn, thought it was okay with just hour and minute. Will change to the TimeSpan version instead.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that i don't understand the actual problem. However, you can also use a `TimeSpan` which might be more readable:

```
var ts1Start = TimeSpan.FromHours(12) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
var ts1End = TimeSpan.FromHours(14);
var ts2Start = TimeSpan.FromHours(18);
var ts2End = TimeSpan.FromHours(21);
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
ASPxCheckBox_ForceClot.Enabled =  (now >= ts1Start && now < ts1End) 
                               || (now >= ts2Start && now < ts2End);
```

One possible problem that my code could fix is that you are using an `if` without `else`. So the checkbox will never be disabled after it was enabled. The code above sets the `Enabled` property always.